# uml plugin for netbeans 6.5.1

Tags: uml, netbeans-plugins

i looked for uml plugin for netbeans 6.5.1 but i can not find the link,
where can i download UML plugin for 'Netbeans 6.5.1' ide ?

and is there any tutorial on how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926197/free-uml-tool-java-to-uml-netbeans). The UML plugin can be found in this version of NetBeans by default.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was not moved from the main installer to the update center and can be installed via the `Tools > Plugins` menu in the IDE.

Five diagram types are supported: activity, class, sequence, state and use case diagrams.